# Unable to get like count for status

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I've been using the the following query for a long time and I've always been able to get the total number of likes (likes count) for each status:

```
$pageInnerData = $facebook->api("/somePageName/posts?fields=created_time,id,message,story,type,picture,shares,likes,comments.limit(5000).fields(id,from,message,like_count,comment_count,created_time)&since={$since}&until={$until}");
```

and by doing the following I was able to retrieve the likes count

```
foreach($pageInnerData['data'] as $pageInfo)
echo $pageInfo['likes']['count'];
```

but the problem is that im unable to get the ['likes']['count'] anymore
why is that? Did facebook change something??

please help this is urgent

and the error that I get is as follows

" Undefined index: count"

Comment: Why don't you `print_r($pageInfo);` to see if it's there?

Comment: its not showing there either, and its not showing in the graph explorer either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With October 2013 Breaking Changes, likes.count field is no longer available in the feed.

You need to make a call for each POST_ID with the summary field enabled.

https://graph.facebook.com/POST_ID/likes?summary=true&access_token=XXXXXXXXXXXX

There will be a "summary" element with a "total_count" field.